# PayPal checkout.js - Get paymentID & payerID

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, express-checkout

I am using PayPal Express Chechkout at my site for single payments. Everything is working fine except that I am unable to get the paymentID and payerID from PayPal. I need those variables to make changes inside my database if a transaction was successfull.

Currently I am using the following code. Transaction in Sandbox and Live Modus are working fine, also the redirection after successfull payment. My problem is, that I am unable to retrieve the paymentID and payerID.

```
<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js'></script>

<div id='paypal-button'></div>

<script>\n";
paypal.Button.render({
// Configure environment
print "env: 'sandbox',
client: {
    sandbox: 'SANDBOX-KEY',
    production: 'PRODUCTION-KEY'
},
// Customize button (optional)\n";
locale: 'de_DE',
style: {
    size: 'small',
    color: 'gold',
    shape: 'pill',
},
// Set up a payment
payment: function (data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.create({
        transactions: [{
            amount: {
                total: '".$price."',
                currency: 'EUR'
            }
        }]
    });
},
// Execute the payment:
// 1. Add an onAuthorize callback
onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.payment.execute({ paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID })
    then(function(res) { window.location.replace ('MY-URL/index.php?func=billing&pp_success=1&paymentID=$paymentID') })
    catch(function(err) { window.location.replace ('MY-URL/index.php?func=billing&pp_error=1') });
},
}, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me, how I need to change my code so that I get the paymentId and payerID from the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

> [PayPal Checkout API](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/api.md)
>
> ...
>
> `actions.payment.execute()` : `() => Promise<PaymentDetails>`
>
> Helper function which calls the PayPal REST API, executes the
>   transaction, and returns a promise containing the [Payment details
>   object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_execute_response) with transaction details, buyer details, etc.
>
> ...

Example:

```js
...
actions.payment.execute({ ... })
  .then(function(res) { ... res.id /* $paymentID */ ... }) ...
...
```